# Получаю java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http:/ когда пытаюсь загрузить файл из сервера

Tags: android, spring, retrofit, retrofit2, rxandroid

Привет получаю ошибку (java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http:) при попытке загрузить файл(.txt) из сервера
вот код сервера

```
@RestController
public class DownloadDbController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(String param) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("src/main/res/123.txt");

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=123.txt");


        Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(header)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .body(resource);

    }
}
```

Апи:

```
public interface GetDb {
    @Streaming
    @GET("{url}")
    Observable<ResponseBody> downloadDB(@Path("url") String url);
}
```

вот конфигурация ретрофита:

```
    public class RetrofitService {
    private static RetrofitService mInstance;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
    private Retrofit mRetrofit;


    private RetrofitService() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor);

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client.build())
                .build();
    }

    public static RetrofitService getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new RetrofitService();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public GetDb getJSONApi() {
        return mRetrofit.create(GetDb.class);
    }
}
```

И вот собственно сам вызов и попытка записать в файл

```
public class SyncDb {
    Context mContext;

    public SyncDb(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void downloadDB(String path) {
        RetrofitService.getInstance()
                .getJSONApi()
                .downloadDB("download")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ResponseBody responseBody) {

                            saveFile(responseBody);
                        Log.d("abc","onNext");


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("abc","error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("abc","Completed");
                    }
                });

public void saveFile(
            ResponseBody responseBody
    ) {
        File folder =new File(mContext.getFilesDir().toString(), "123.txt");
        folder.mkdirs();

        File unzipMe = new File(folder, "123.txt");
        if (!unzipMe.exists()){
            try {
                unzipMe.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(unzipMe));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            bos.write(responseBody.bytes());
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: http запретили просто так использовать

Comment: @Style-7 и что мне делать?

Comment: такие вопросы тут уже не прилично задавать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: @Style-7 я пофиксил это заранее, так что дело не в этом